# Reindexing Search in 2013

Tags: search, powershell, search-engine

In SDL Tridion 2011, there was an executable to rebuild the Solr search collection. How do we re-index search in [2013](/questions/tagged/2013) ?

Comment: Not to be critical but I don't think SE is the place for asking hypothetical / "pop quiz" questions (even if it is just an attempt to build up a repo of questions). Relevant: http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/23/really-basic-primer-questions-should-we-add-them

Comment: Just search for "Reindexing search indexes" in documentation. First try it and then, if you have a problem - ask specific question

Comment: As per FAQ, it is highly recommended to add questions along with answers so that it can help others as well to the question poster in future. I am editing your question a bit and putting the answer to it so that it might help others (I would have been more happy if you could have put answer to it)

Comment: Also, as per FAQ, it is not bad if the Q & A are posted just to build up repo as far as it is adding value to the objective of the site.

Comment: Indeed, it's fine to ask and immediately answer a question in order to document a solution to a problem, but asking a question you already know the answer to and leaving it open doesn't really fall under that umbrella.

Comment: @AntP: Agree with You, but if we ignore the individual contribution, from a third person perspective, at this very moment, the question (or rather Q & A) looks good to me.

Comment: @PankajGaur Now that it has been liberally edited and answered, yes :P

Comment: I had the debate on asking and answering myself with others. I thought quickly answering was okay, others didn't. This was a real question, though. I wasn't sure of the difference between optimizing (and which user to use) and re-indexing, then I missed the difference between 2011 and 2013 (duh). I just wanted to get this out there but sure, I'll avoid the pop quiz tone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use powershell for re-indexing your search indexes.

1. Execute  `Sync-TcmSearchIndex` on powershell to reindex all publication
2. Execute `Sync-TcmSearchIndex` with a TcmRepositoryIds parameter containing list of publication URIs if you want to re-index a set of publication or a specific publication

Source and Reference: [SDL Live Documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=reindexing&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1371800397735&currentQuery=reindexing&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_CD6B11B846164C18ABB0FE2625785E21&query=reindexing&scope=&filename=ReindexingSearch.xml&docid=task_CD6B11B846164C18ABB0FE2625785E21&inner_id=&tid=fb0a83ab-ed09-458d-af63-797dadbc63fa&addHistory=true&resource=)

Comment: Thanks and accepted! I eventually found the answer after some searching. :-)

Comment: How to rebuild search index periodically??

Comment: Abdul: This might help you:

http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/004_SharePointActions/012_SchedulingPowerShell.htm

Comment: Pankaj's example answers, "how would you periodically run PowerShell scripts _without Tridion_?" So a preferred approach isn't Tridion specific per se.